# Why is res.render not working after post request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rendering, ejs

I've been trying to fix this for a while now. The problem is actually when I send a post request via the fetch api and then catch it with the post request in the node js file it should normally render the error page but it doesn't. How does this happen?

ps: don't mind the text. I am dutch.

node js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const { emailFormSchema } = require("./schemas.js");
const rateLimiter = require("express-rate-limit");
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    require("dotenv").config();
}
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const ExpressError = require("./utils/ExpressError");
const ejsMate = require("ejs-mate");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const Swal = require("sweetalert2");
const { Console } = require("console");

// Setting up ejs and the stylesheets
app.engine("ejs", ejsMate);
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "/views"));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.json());


// POST route for form
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/contact", limiter, validateForm, (req, res, next) => {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: "gmail",
        auth: {
            user: process.env.email,
            pass: process.env.pass,
        },
    });
    const mailOptions = {
        From: req.body.email,
        // to moet nog aangepast worden naar mamas email
        to: process.env.email,
        subject: `Nieuw bericht van ${req.body.email}`,
        text: `naam: ${req.body.name},
bericht: ${req.body.message}`,
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.send("error token");
        } else {
            console.log(`mail verzonden: ${info.response}`);
            res.send("success");
        }
    });
});

// HOME
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("./pages/home.ejs");
});

let message = "";

app.post("/error", (req, res, next) => {
    const msg = req.body.message;
    message = req.body.message;
    console.log("error message is:", msg);

    // res.redirect("/error");
    res.redirect("/error");
});

app.get("/error", (req, res, next) => {
    if (message) {
        console.log("hitted");
        res.render("./pages/error", { message });
        // next(new ExpressError(message, 404));
    } else {
        next(new ExpressError("Pagina niet gevonden", 404));
    }
});

app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
    next(new ExpressError("Pagina niet gevonden", 404));
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    const { statusCode = 500, message } = err;
    console.log("Message in error handeler is:", message);

    res.render("./pages/error", { message, statusCode });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because post requesy is not for rendering page.
Post request is for data transfers. Like rest api. You should use res.

So you should use res.write instead of res.render.

Or sending GET request for rendering.

P.S. I'm very sorry for my terrible english skill.

Comment: I'm sorry but where do I need to change the res.render to res.write